# Shell Script Error- can't execute the command

Tags: shell

I wrote a bash shell script to rename the file,

```
#!/bin/bash

#renaming the files

for filename in 'find . -name "PostStackTemplate*"' 
do
   echo $filename 
   newName='echo $filename | sed -e "s/TestVersion/Version2/g" $filename'
   mv $filename  $newName 
done
```

When I execute this script, I am getting the output as

```
find . -name "PostStackTemplate*" 
mv: invalid option -- n 
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: If you actually used single quotes instead of backquotes, that's your problem.  You want: for filename in $( find .... ) and newName=$( echo ... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to assign the output of the `sed` command to the `newName` variable:

```
newName=$(echo $filename | sed -e "s/TestVersion/Version2/g" $filename)
```

Otherwise, `newName` would contain just the string being assigned.